# How to refresh conditional formats after closing a zoom in box

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form which has some fields which have conditionalformats which are linked to values which get entered via a zoom in box. In other words, to update each conditionally formatted field, the user clicks on the control and a zoom in box appears allowing the user to enter the data.  In the following situation the conditional formatting takes effect only after i close the main form and re-enter. In other words, it does not update automatically once the user access the zoom in form.  I tried to put a refresh command on the close zoom in form event, but it is giving me an error. Below is the code i put on the close event of the zoom in:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
    Forms("frmprojectphasemasterboard").Form("frmprojectphase")!Description = Me.txtZoom
    Forms("frmprojectphasemasterboard").Form("frmprojectphase").Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? It might be syntax, as logically the approach seems ok. Try replacing your refresh instruction with this: "Forms!frmProjectMasterBoard!frmProjectPhase.Form.Refresh". Is the zoom box modal (ie is it opened as a dialog)?

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Mr. Bingham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Forms!frmProjectMasterBoard!frmProjectPhase.Form.Refresh
```